# Signalr on Azure Service fabric

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr, azure-service-fabric

I created a sample Signalr stateless service and tried to run on my local host and I am getting the error below.

Did anyone able to run their Signalr service on service fabric?

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus',
>   HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false. Replica had
>   multiple failures during open on _Node_0. API call:
>   IStatelessServiceInstance.Open(); Error =
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException (-2146232828) Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext
>   context)    at
>   HR.Lib.ServiceFabric.Listeners.OwinCommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.d__13.MoveNext()
>   For more information see: http://aka.ms/sfhealth

Comment: can you add the code from `CreateServiceInstanceListeners`?

Comment: Matter of fact, I played around with SignalR earlier this month on Service Fabric, are you using the 2.2 or the alpa for core?

Comment: I am using AspNet.SignalR.Core, Owin, versioning.. I am just doing a POC to see how I can host this in service fabric. Do I have to fix the port so that the user can connect to the hub at that port? We are using ngnix so is there a possibility to access the port through ngnix port.

Comment: @LoekD I don't see that. Where can I find it,

Comment: @BartdeRuijter Is there any sample code that you can share,

Comment: @BartdeRuijter Did you use 2.2 or core?

Comment: a very basic thing which i also forget sometime is to stop the IIS which generally use the port 80, check which port your app is using in service fabric. The reason may be that port is already in use on local machine.

Comment: @SatyaTanwar I did check that. But no luck. Did you use Signalr in your service fabric application

Comment: Not yet but planning to use it soon, it’s still in alpha. Also if possible could you paste more details about the error.

Comment: I have created a sample Service fabric stateless service and added the basic code to run the app. I used Signalr.core dll, When I run it, I am getting the above error. I don't know what's creating the error. I don't think it is machine specific issue. Do you mind creating a sample app with Signalr in it and run to see how it behaves.